# Apache .htaccess redirects for URL's with Arabic characters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, arabic

I have been trying to add some .htaccess redirection rules for URL's with parts in Arabic. Obviously, I am using the Arabic part, URL encoded, but still Apache seems to not be able to resolve the URL, either catch it in the condition or redirect it. Does anyone have any experience on the subject?

This is one line from the config file

```
RewriteRule ^arabic/%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B3-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%82-%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%‌​A9-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8‌​6%D8%AF(.*)$ /blog/sa-ar/%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B3-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%82-%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF‌​%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A8%D8%A7%‌​D9%86%D8%AF/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you show your existing rules and clarify where the problem is.

Comment: Sure, this is one line from my config: RewriteRule ^arabic/%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B3-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%82-%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF(.*)$ /blog/sa-ar/%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B3-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%82-%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: As bigOTHER answered, your encoding doesn't seem to be right. Furthermore, I was able to achieve Apache rewrites in the past with actual raw Arabic text in the file. So not url encoded. You should try that too.

Comment: What URL are you trying to redirect here?

Comment: OK, thanks Eric, I will try using the actual Arabic String, even though I am pretty sure I tried that already.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with "م" which is "%D9%85"
Just use this:

```
RewriteRule ^arabic/([\s\S]*)$ /blog/sa-ar/$1
```

that worked for me!
In fact you have to use `^([\s\S]*)$` instead of `^(.*)$`